# Different Maven dependencies having same package name

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Say there are 2 Maven dependencies foo and bar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Dependency foo contains the class `com.example.hello.There` and bar contains the class `com.example.hello.Here`

When I write code that needs `Here.class` I put in `import com.example.hello.Here`. The code compiles and works fine but Intellij sometimes complains that it **Cannot resolve symbol 'Here'**, possibly because it is statically looking for it in dependency foo.

Unfortunately I cannot change the dependencies' structure. How do I stop Intellij from complaining here?

Comment: you need to format the question with more info on the pom.xml and dependencies included. And no it's not looking for the dependency in `foo` when it reads that.

Comment: This should just work normally. If it doesn't, then either there is something wrong with the way your project is set up, or there is a bug in IntelliJ.

Comment: @nullpointer Added the dependency list which is the same as my actual code with just the names changed.

Comment: @Jesper it does work normally. Code compiles and even runs fine. Only Intellij complains.

Comment: It should work out of the box. Do you have auto-import enabled or did you just forget to update the maven project (reload button in the maven sidebar)?

Comment: It should work fine. I would stick with the point that no it's not looking for the dependency in `foo` when it reads your import unless you specify so. I doubt the maven configs/sync or duplicacy of code in the packages to what I can see.

Comment: Close the project, delete the .idea folder and all *.i* files. Reopen the project from the pom, doing a full import. See if the problem still exists.